# jQuery redirected on response

Tags: jquery, json, redirect

Im trying to display images for every result I get.

I have the current code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var frm = $('#searchmovie');
            frm.submit(function (ev) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //alert('Got response from server!');
                        if(data == "404"){
                            alert('404, no results found');
                        }
                        else{
                            data = $.parseJSON(data);

                            $.each(data, function(index,movie) {
                                //alert(movie.imdb_id);
                                content += '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                                                <a class="poster-container" href="/movie?imdb_id='+ movie.imdb_id +'">
                                                <img src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxx&h=376&i='+movie.imdb_id+'" height="376" width="251">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>';

                            });
                            //content = '<div class="img_wrapper">';

                            $('#movieresults').append(content);
                            //$('#movieresults').append(JSON.stringify(data)); 
                        }

                    }
                });

                ev.preventDefault();
            });
      });
```

The problem is that when I use the alert(movie.imdb_id) below:

```
else{
       data = $.parseJSON(data);
       $.each(data, function(index,movie) {
          alert(movie.imdb_id);

       });
    }
```

I get the alerts and stay on my current page. Which is what I want.
But when I use the "content thing" I get redirected to the API:s res.json page...? Why is that?

Comment: Does 
```$('#movieresults').append('<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">
                                                <a class="poster-container" href="/movie?imdb_id='+ movie.imdb_id +'">
                                                <img src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxx&h=376&i='+movie.imdb_id+'" height="376" width="251">
                                                </a>
                                            </div>');```

redirect you?

Comment: Well I think. Because when I use alert only, I'm not redirected..? I comment " $('#movieresults').append(content);" also.

Comment: try to move ev.preventDefault() before the ajax call ?

Comment: Both writing as Klepthys said and what Hacketo said results in no difference.. :(

Comment: is removing the entire ajax call also redirect ?, because, that seem to be the default behavior of the form that is fired.

Comment: You mean all from $.ajax and below?

Comment: Now nothing happens. So im not redirected by default. It seems so odd, because when I have only alert, or "$('#movieresults').append(JSON.stringify(data)); " Im not redirected..?

Comment: does your code actually have carriage returns inside `content += '...'`? Because if so that would be a syntax error and the script won't run

Comment: Ehm, what exactly is a carriage return?

Comment: a new line, well technically they're not the same thing but the enter key will produce a new line also

Comment: Well then I dont think my script works, because when I change the content to look like this: content += '<kbd>enter</kbd>'; the script wont do anything but initiate the search on the API..? But when searching for nothing, the right alert will show up.

Comment: I don't think you understand, ill post an answer to make it  more clear

Comment: Yeah probably, thanks!

Comment: You should not need `$.parseJSON(data);` per [documentation of jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). `The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter....` The dataType states `If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object`,.... So jQuery by default usually decodes a JSON string into a Javascript Object and passed the object as the data parameters.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I didn't have it in the beginning, only to kind of debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content += '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center"> <-- THE LINE BREAK HERE IS INVALID SYNTAX! 
               <a class="poster-container" href="/movie?imdb_id='+ movie.imdb_id +'">
                  <img src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxx&h=376&i='+movie.imdb_id+'" height="376" width="251">
               </a>
             </div>';
```

You can do two things:

1)

```
content += '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">';
content +=   '<a class="poster-container" href="/movie?imdb_id='+ movie.imdb_id +'">';
content +=      '<img src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxx&h=376&i='+movie.imdb_id+'" height="376" width="251">';
content +=     '</a>';
content +=  '</div>';
```

2)

```
content += '<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 text-center">' +
              '<a class="poster-container" href="/movie?imdb_id='+ movie.imdb_id +'">'+
                 '<img src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?apikey=xxxxxx&h=376&i='+movie.imdb_id+'" height="376" width="251">'+
              '</a>'+
           '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks! Im trying this and the script will run (gets to the API) but the response is not appended. It wont even append with this: content += '<p>Movie ID: '+movie.imdb_id+'</p>';

Comment: where is `content` initially defined?

Comment: It wasen't.. Now it works.. :) You are awesome and I am very sloppy!

Comment: I would recommend that you download an ide for yourself such as netbeans or aptana. It will show you syntax errors in your code before you try to run it, editing code in notepad will only lead to headaches